# Warning CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved while running C# application in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mono, c#

I've installed mono, and I am able to compile and execute command line C# applications to learn syntax. However, I keep getting this after compiling:

```
warning CS8001: SDK path could not be resolved
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

After searching around the web, almost every answer said to install libmono-winforms2.0-cil. However, I found out that was only for Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. 
I also read that libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil replaces this, but it's already installed and does nothing.

How can I get rid of this warning, and what does it even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the call to mcs by changing the -sdk argument.  Also make sure you've got everything you need installed.